# System.IO.FileStream does not contain a definition for 'ReadLine' and no extension method 'ReadLine' of type. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read  a basic text file that contains 1 byte of data.
Apparently, ReadLine isn't defined and I don't know what's wrong. See code below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class loadGame : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    FileStream file = new FileStream("save.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    int introPlayed = file.ReadLine();
    if (introPlayed == 1)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("game");
        file.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("intro");
        file.Close();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Well it doesn't. Maybe use [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)? It _Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding._ FileStream is more general and will let you read anything including all sort of binary data files

Comment: Using the static methods of the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) class simplifies your life: `string line = File.ReadLines("save.txt").FirstOrDefault();`. No opening or closing, etc.

Comment: Even when using a StreamReader, check its documentation for ReadLine. It doesnt' return an int. Also, avoid using a FileStream or StreamReader without using `using` (again, look at thee documentation for StreamReader for an example of how to do it right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx). Or use the approach mentioned by Olivier...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to go for the StreamReader method and copied the code from the Microsoft site - however, Unity is now telling me it cannot read from a closed StreamReader. Once again help appreciated.